# How to Implement sp_core:Encode?

Tags: pallet, frame

I've copied Kulupu's `difficulty` [pallet](https://github.com/kulupu/kulupu/blob/master/frame/difficulty/src/lib.rs) and tried to build my node after connecting the pallet. The `decl_storage!` macro in that pallet looks like this:

```
decl_storage! {
trait Store for Module<T: Config> as Difficulty {
    /// Past difficulties and timestamps, from earliest to latest.
    // TODO Bug here
    PastDifficultiesAndTimestamps: [Option<DifficultyAndTimestamp<T::Moment>>; 60] = [None; DIFFICULTY_ADJUST_WINDOW as usize];
    /// Current difficulty.
    pub CurrentDifficulty get(fn difficulty) build(|config: &GenesisConfig| {
        config.initial_difficulty
    }): Difficulty;
    /// Initial difficulty.
    pub InitialDifficulty config(initial_difficulty): Difficulty;
}
```

}

And the error I get is:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[std::option::Option<DifficultyAndTimestamp<<T as pallet_timestamp::Config>::Moment>>; 60]: sp_core::Encode` is not satisfied
  --> pallets/difficulty/src/lib.rs:40:1
   |
40 | / decl_storage! {
41 | |     trait Store for Module<T: Config> as Difficulty {
42 | |         /// Past difficulties and timestamps, from earliest to latest.
43 | |         // TODO Implement sp_core::Encode, Decode for
...  |
51 | |     }
52 | | }
   | |_^ the trait `sp_core::Encode` is not implemented for `[std::option::Option<DifficultyAndTimestamp<<T as pallet_timestamp::Config>::Moment>>; 60]`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <[T; N] as sp_core::Encode>
             <[T] as sp_core::Encode>
note: required by a bound in `hidden_include::storage::generator::StorageValue`
  --> /home/creestl/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/1b57cff/frame/support/src/storage/generator/value.rs:30:27
   |
30 | pub trait StorageValue<T: FullCodec> {
   |                           ^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `hidden_include::storage::generator::StorageValue`
   = note: this error originates in the macro `decl_storage` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

It says that `sp_core:Encode` (and Decode and some others...) is not implemented for `Option<DifficultyAndTimestamp<...>>` even though there is such `Derive` in `difficulty` pallet:

```
#[derive(Encode, Decode, TypeInfo, Clone, Copy, Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct DifficultyAndTimestamp<M> {
    pub difficulty: Difficulty,
    pub timestamp: M,
}
```

**ALSO** if I just clone whole Kulupu's repo and `cd` to `difficulty` crate and run `cargo build --release` it builds no problem. But if I do the same in my crate (with the *same* code) it won't build.

How do I fix this?
Should I provide a whole error massage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of error is usually misleading.

It is clear that `Encode` is being derived in the code snippet above, but as you see the compiler is complaining that it isn't being derived.

This usually happens when there are mismatched dependencies. For example, one part of your code uses `sp-core = v1.0.0` and the other uses `sp-core = v2.0.0`.

In this case, if the derive is generating `Encode` for `v1.0.0`, but then some `v2.0.0` code checks this, it will say that `Encode` is not derived because of the version mismatch.

I don't have a specific solution for you since I don't know your exact project structure, but I would check that all versions of crates you are using, especially the versions of Substrate, are in agreement.

Comment: That solved the issue. Thanks!